# Gnome3 Freezing / Hanging / Unresponsive - can't restart

Tags: 16.04, gnome, keyboard, mouse, multiseat

I am running UbuntuGNOME 16.04. The Gnome3 interface is useful because of its touch support (helpful for various peripherals, as this is a desktop), but it hangs every so often - usually with specific programs (Firefox with a number of tabs open, Virtual Box running a CAD program on Windows 7 x64 Ultimate, etc).

The mouse responds to moving around the screen, but doesn't accept other inputs (no clicks, and it keeps the state it was in - e.g. a 'move cross', a waiting icon, etc). **The keyboard doesn't accept ANY inputs.**

I have tried ALT+F2-->R-->ENTER, Ctrl+Alt+F1, Ctl+Alt+F2 (or F3, etc). Nothing works, as the keyboard is 'unresponsive'

HOWEVER ... this is a multiseat (2, to be precise) system. The other seat is responsive.

**Q1: How do I overcome the keyboard not being responsive?**

**Q2: Can I restart the Gnome instance in Seat1 from Seat2?**

THANKS!

Comment: Have a problem with identical symptoms.  No events in any of the normal logs, including Xorg.0.log.  Might have to run Unity with extended debugging, but I haven't quite gotten around to figuring that out.

Comment: I think that I had a bad Quadro 5000 graphics card (there were two). When I took out one of them, the problem shifted -- Gnome would still freeze (especially bad with Ubuntu 17.10 after the revert back to Gnome desktop - first time I print every session, it freezes) - but if I wait, it will auto-restart. I can always prompt it by switching using Ctrl+Alt+F7 --> Ctrl+Alt+F5 --> then switch back using Ctrl+Alt+F1. Sorta strange, but it prompts it to reset. Hope it gets fixed in Ubuntu 18.04. I think the problem was the Graphics Card causing freezing with the RAM somehow. It was strange.

Comment: Also, I tried removing RAM, removing the other Quadro, and switching which slots each Quadro was in (individually and together), but the unresponsive-keyboard problem basically went away when I removed that graphics card.