# GNOME freezing at random times

Tags: 16.04, gnome, freeze

Periodically, and at random times, I have GNOME freezing on my computer and I am unable to recover. I have to hold the reset button on the server to restart. Clearly this is not a good solution.

Symptoms:

> 1. keyboard not responsive.
> 2. mouse pointer moves around screen fine
> 3. mouse-clicks no response
> 4. mouse-hover no response (ie, cannot see tooltips, pointer does not change shape)

I have attempted every possible keystroke I can think of to get to command line but as mentioned in #1 above, the keyword responds to nothing. I have tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, etc.

System information:

```
AMD FX8350
24G RAM
Ubuntu 16.04.3
Gnome Shell 3.18.5
Linux etool 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 10:13:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Wine 3.0
Dash-to-panel 11
```

This appears to be the same unsolved issue as mentioned here: [Gnome3 Freezing / Hanging / Unresponsive - can't restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840668/gnome3-freezing-hanging-unresponsive-cant-restart).

Comment: I experienced a similar issue on Debian 9 using gnome 3. It turned out to be pulseaudio kernel module failing to load. I found it by watching all systemd logs and triggering the freeze by switching workspaces. You can watch all logs by running: ```sudo journalctl -f
``` It seems odd to me that gnome tries to reload kernel modules when switching workspaces...